# linq where -> compare to list of longs

Tags: asp.net, linq, list, linq-to-sql

I have the following linq query

```
var q = from e in dbTov.assignedTaxonomyToContents
where e.taxonomy_id == lsTaxID[0]
|| e.taxonomy_id == lsTaxID[1]
|| e.taxonomy_id == lsTaxID[2]
select e;
```

But, lsTaxID can have a few more items in it (I don't know how much, it is dynamic on each page request).

Is there an intuitive way to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: The way you wrote it means that taxonomy_id has to be equal to lsTaxID[0] and lsTaxID[1] and lsTaxID[2], did you really mean that or any of them?

Comment: @vc 74 indeed, i meant or, not and

Comment: You should have indicated that you were using Linq to SQL, my answer only applies to Linq to objects (I'll delete it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Contains:

```
var q = from e in dbTov.assignedTaxonomyToContents
where lsTaxID.Contains(e.taxonomy_id)
select e;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
where lsTaxId.Contains(e.taxonomy_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var q = 
    from e 
    in dbTov.assignedTaxonomyToContents 
    where lsTaxID.Contains(e.taxonomy_id);
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. I think you meant to have `(e.taxonomy_id)` at the end.

Comment: I think it got chopped when I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the taxonomy ID has to match any of the items in the `lsTaxID` array:

```
dbTov.assignedTaxonomyToContents
  .Where(e => lsTaxID.Any(id => id == e.taxonomy_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless all the elements of lsTaxID[..] are the same, your example code will never select anything. Try this;

```
var q = from e in dbTov.assignedTaxonomyToContents
where lsTaxID.Contains(e.taxonomy_id)
select e;
```